# Compress(encrypt) string with alphanumeric & special characters to alphanumeric and convert back the compressed alpanumeric to original string

Tags: java, encryption, serialization, alphanumeric

I have a string ex: "12345678923|asdd-asda-sdas-dasd-asdd-asda-sdas-dsdd" (length >50), I am passing this string to an API-X which consumes the string and returns the same string in callBack API-Y. 
But API-X doesn't support the input string with following conditions.

1.Length should be less than 40.
2.No special characters allowed.
3.It can be alpha numeric.

I am expecting the same string as input to my API-Z from the callBack API-Y. I can't change the behavior of API-X as it is vendor API.

I tried following approaches to achieve this scenario but none of them satisfy all 3 conditions.

1.convert all special characters to alphanumeric to satisfy condition (2) and (3), But Condition (1) will fail as the converted string length is crossing 100 characters.
2.convert string to byte array and byte array to string. Which is again failing condition (1)
3.Thought to zip the string and unzip, But this fails condition (2) and (3)

Please suggest some algorithm to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're looking for a bijection between (the set of all Strings) and (the set of all Strings of up to 40 letters and numbers), right?

Comment: Yes and It should work independently without any other dependency like (key) to convert and revert back to original.

Comment: Right.  I have a 10 litre bucket.  I would like to fill it with 1000 litres of water.  If you can help me solve that, I will help you find the bijection that you're looking for.  Incidentally, one of the properties of a bijection is that its domain and its range have exactly the same number of elements.

Comment: seems to be impossible but there might be some ways to compress it and then to restructure  back to original string.

Comment: No.  It's impossible.  There's simply no such thing as a bijection between two sets of different sizes.

Comment: Without knowing a priori that the input string set has low entropy the approach is doomed to failure and not worth trying.

Comment: Thanks @DawoodibnKareem and JamesKPolk for confirming.